# Who was Toph's husband

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

[Lin Beifong](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Lin_Beifong) is described as the daughter of [Toph Beifong](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Toph_Beifong), the blind earthbender who teaches Aang earthbending, but her father is not named. Who is he?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**UPDATE** [Dec-2014]:

The creators finally decided to name [Lin Beifong](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Lin_Beifong)'s father.

***Season 4, Episode 10: Operation Beifong* :**

> (while Bolin, Opal, Toph and Lin are sitting by the fire for dinner)
>   **Bolin**: So, here's something I've always been curious about! *Who's Lin's dad?*
>   **Toph**: He was a guy named ***Kanto***. Nice man, but it didn't really work out between us.
>   **Bolin**: Aaaaaaand... okay!

Aaaaannd.. That's it. Lin's dad is some guy named Kanto (Toph pronounced it *Kahn-Toe*). No more info (yet).

Toph has a second daughter, [Suyin Beifong](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Suyin_Beifong), half-sister of Lin, and we still don't know who Su's father is. Toph probably had multiple husbands/lovers. Let's wait for the writers to reveal more!

---

EARLIER [Jun-2012]:

The official(?) Legend of Korra family tree (below) seen floating around the interwebs simply says "Unknown father" for Lin Beifong.

[image: The Legend of Korra family tree]

Speculation or reverse engineering of the facts we already know from both the series so far isn't sufficient to answer this question.

We will need to patiently await the creators for the answers to this one and more ('What happened to Zuko's mother?', 'Who is Amon?' etc.) through the show or through associated print media such as the [comics](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Avatar%3A_The_Last_Airbender_comics) and [magazines](http://www.buddytv.com/articles/avatar-the-last-airbender/avatar-magazine-now-available-11207.aspx) based on the series.

Picture corrections (spoiler warning):

> - Bumi developed Airbender abilities in the third season
>  - Toph Beifong has two daughters (Lin and Suyin Beifong)
>  - Bolin is an Earth bender and discovered in the third season he can Lava bend too.

Comment: Why downvote? The answer to a question such as this depends completely on the fragment of imagination of the creator, and I was merely restating that! Unless the actual creator decided to answer this or made a revelation on the show/other media, there would be no concrete answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's Sokka. In *Avatar: Legend of Korra*, Lin was an ex-gf of Tenzin. If Sokka is Lin's father, then Lin is Tenzin's cousin. That makes absolutely no sense. I think Toph's husband is someone who is not introduced in *The Last Airbender*. :)

Comment: Is there any evidence that people don't intermarry in the Avatar universe?