# What is the relationship between Tenzin and Lin?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra, marriage

There was a discussion about who Toph married and another about who Sokka married. In these, they mentioned that it wouldn't make sense and wouldn't be okay (or something along those lines) because it would make Tenzin and Lin cousins. What sort of relationship do Tenzin and Lin have? What relations did each of their parents have?

Comment: This is more of a discussion question, which isn't well suited to our format. Check out [the tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how we work!

Comment: You might see nothing wrong with it, but a large chunk of their potential audience would.

Comment: Lin and Tenzin's relationship would be illegal in most of the US; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin_marriage_law_in_the_United_States_by_state and while the world is 'airbender' is different from our own world it's simply too much of a gap for audiences to cross.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will only address whether Tenzin and Lin are cousins. Why some people might not like cousins to intermarry in *Avatar: The Legend of Korra* is both interesting and **off-topic**.

### I don't think they are cousins

- Tenzin was the son of of Aang and Katara
- Lin is the daughter of Toph and Kanto.

Toph does not have any siblings.

Katara's only sibling is Sokka.

Sokka is not the father of either Lin or Tenzin.

Aang had no living siblings, to my knowledge.

Kanto, I'm not sure about, but I don't believe he has any relationship to any of the other three parents of Tenzin and Lin.

For Tenzin and Lin to be cousins, one of the parents of one must be a sibling of one of the parents of the other.

This does not appear to be the case.

Some people have speculated that Kanto is Sokka, **but I don't think there is any evidence of that.**

The discussion [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14976/who-was-tophs-husband) seems to be a good fit to what you mentioned.